# Conditions for point lying inside triangle formed by three complex numbers.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles, coordinate-systems

The question states

> $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are three non-collinear complex numbers such that
>   $$z=\frac{lz_1+mz_2+nz_3}{l+m+n}$$
>   lies inside the triangle formed by $z_1,z_2,z_3$. If $l,m,n$ are the roots of the equation $x^3+3x^2+px+q=0$ then comment on the signs of $p$ and $q$.

Using $l+m+n=-3$, i get $z=-\frac{lz_1+mz_2+nz_3}{3}$.

But I am unable to proceed further.

At first glance, the expression looked similar to the section formula for two points. I'm interested to know if there are any similarities with that.

Also, can conditions be imposed on $l,m,n$ in the general case, that is, without giving $l+m+n=3$?

Comment: if $z = \alpha_1 z_1 + \alpha_2 z_2 + \alpha_3 z_3$ and $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 1$, then $z$ lies inside or on the triangle iff $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3 \ge 0$ ($ > 0$ if $z$ lies inside the triangle). If you scale $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ to get $l, m, n$, you find the sign of $l, m, n$ are the same.

Comment: I am not familiar with this..Is there a proof?

Comment: $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ are the [baricentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) for a point with respect to a triangle. Look at the wiki page for more info. Essentially, $\alpha_1 \ge 0$ means the point $z$ is lying on the same side as $z_1$ with respect to the line $z_2z_3$.